# How do I install ONLY the bcp program for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, installation, bcp

Just like the title says. All I need is the BCP program on my client computer. The BCP will be from a remote machine, so I don't want to install SQL Express or the management studio or any of that.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry Mark, I posted this on the wrong site. Thanks for the move :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported way is to install one of the SQL Server distribution packages (MSI). You are prevented by the terms of the license you agreed to to copy the bpc.exe file to another location (or, for the matter, any other file or 'crap' as you call them). If you don't like this situation, then feel free to build your own bulk utility executable and redistribute it as you like. The interface is called [`IRowsetFastload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131708.aspx) is is documented, good luck.

Comment: One of the proposed solutions was exactly that, but bcp can do what we want, so we figured that would be easier than creating and maintaining a custom program just for this one task.